# Coloring an $m \times n$ rectangular board with $2-$ colors

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

> Given an $m \times n$ table, where $m<n$, each cell is colored Red or Blue. Suppose that every column contains at least one Red cell. Prove that there is a Red cell such that the number of Red cells in its row is larger than the number of red cells in it column.

I think this involves the pigeonhole principle, but I'm just not sure how to go about it. Any tips or help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: $m\times n$ looks correct, if it's $n\times m$ the statement wouldn't hold.

Comment: Yes you're right.. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X$ be the set of rows, $Y$ the set of columns: $|X|=m\lt n=|Y|$.

Let $E\subseteq X\times Y$ be the set of red cells.

For $x\in X$ let $d(x)=|\{y\in Y:(x,y)\in E\}|$, the number of red cells in row $x$.

For $y\in Y$ let $d(y)=|\{x\in X:(x,y)\in E\}|$, the number of red cells in column $y$.

Let $X_0=\{x\in X:d(x)\ne0\}\subseteq X$ and $Y_0=\{y\in Y:d(y)\ne0\}=Y$.

I have to prove that $d(x)\gt d(y)$ for some $(x,y)\in E$.
Assume for a contradiction that $d(x)\le d(y)$ whenever $(x,y)\in E$; in other words, $\frac1{d(y)}\le\frac1{d(x)}$ whenever $(x,y)\in E$. (Note that $d(x),d(y)\gt0$ when $(x,y)\in E$.) Then
$$\sum_{(x,y)\in E}\frac1{d(y)}\le\sum_{(x,y)\in E}\frac1{d(x)}.$$
Since
$$\sum_{(x,y)\in E}\frac1{d(x)}=\sum_{x\in X_0}\frac{d(x)}{d(x)}=|X_0|\le|X|=m$$
and
$$\sum_{(x,y)\in E}\frac1{d(y)}=\sum_{y\in Y_0}\frac{d(y)}{d(y)}=|Y_0|=|Y|=n$$
it follows that $n\le m$, contradiction the assumption that $m\lt n$.

**Remark.** This puzzle is a lemma from matching theory in disguise. Namely, this is how you show that, if $G$ is a bipartite graph with partite sets $X,Y$, if there are no isolated vertices in $Y$, and if $\deg(x)\le\deg(y)$ whenever $x\in X$, $y\in Y$, and $(x,y)\in E(G)$, then thee is a matching in $G$ which covers $Y$.

Comment: Thanks for this prove. Really nice

Answer (score 3):

Let $R_i$ be the number of red cells in row $i$ and $R_j$ the number of red cells in column $j$.

Now suppose the negation of the statement were true. Then, for every red cell, if its location on the grid is $(i, j)$, $R_i \leq R_j$.

Form the sequence $(i_j)$ by choosing a row index for each column in the following way: if the column $j$ contains a red cell at $(i, j)$ whose row index, $i$, is not already in the sequence, choose $i$. If all of the row indices corresponding to cells in the column $j$ are already in the sequence, choose any $i$. This ensures that for every row containing at least one red cell, its index will appear in the sequence. Furthermore, since $n>m$, there is a row containing at least one red cell whose index will appear more than once in the sequence.

Since we assumed that $R_i \leq R_j$ for all red cells $(i, j)$, the total number of red cells must then satisfy:

$R_{i_1} + R_{i_2}+...+R_{i_n} \leq R_{tot}$

where we have counted the total red cells by the column in which they appear.
But if we count the cells by the row in which they appear:

$R_1 + R_2 + ... + R_m = R_{tot}$

But since at least one index corresponding to a row with at least one red cell will appear twice in the sequence $(i_j)$, $R_{p_0}+R_{p_1}+...+R_{p_k} \leq 0$  for some indices $p_l$ such that $R_{p_l}$ is at least one, a contradiction.

Note that in the last part, we have removed the terms corresponding to rows with no red cells, if there are any, which leaves the sum unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for this